# How can I add these two lines using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

How can I add these two lines using Bootstrap? I'm trying to make a header like this . A TITLE having two blank borders in both sides in top and bottom. Is it possible to make with Bootstrap? I'm a noob lol.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-danger">
  <div class="h1">HEADER</div>
  <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-bottom border-danger">
</div>
```

[image: h1 with two lines]

Comment: Please post the code you've attempted

Comment: Please tag just one version of Bootstrap. They're somewhat different and it's not clear which you're using.

Comment: there is no one noob we are all learning here

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have used a h1 between 2 span tags and sized h1 to 3 of 12

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <span class="col border-top border-5 border-dark"></span>
    <h1 class="col-3 text-center">HEADER</h1>
    <span class="col border-bottom border-5 border-dark"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to have alignment issues. A two-unit column doesn't fit the text. Also, some explanation is expected. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

the `flex` display option allows for the automatic alignment to the right and left of the text using `flex-grow: 1` on the child-elements. Using this on 2 elements surrounding a third also centers this third one. You may specify a width on one of the growing ones to get an offset header.

*Note that bootstraps 'row' class also uses* `display: flex`.

Move the border by applying `margin-top`s as per usual in to fine-tune their vertical alignment. Preserve the same height of the elements for aligned borders (e.g. use h1 on both to apply the same height).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-fill border-top border-2 border-danger h1"></div>
    <div class="h1">HEADER</div>
    <div class="flex-fill border-bottom border-2 border-danger h1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-fill border-top border-2 border-danger h1"></div>
    <div class="h1 text-center">HEADER</div>
    <div class="flex-fill border-bottom border-2 border-danger h1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get close using [flex layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) and [margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/). Some tweaking may be needed due to the line height of the heading element.

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.h1.lh-min {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex">
  <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-danger flex-grow-1 align-self-start m-0 mt-1">
  <div class="h1 lh-min m-0">HEADER</div>
  <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-bottom border-danger flex-grow-1 align-self-end m-0">
</div>
```